# Javascript background color change (strange bug)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a strange bug: if I click 2 or 3 times on a `div` element then the Opera browser changes the background color of this element to transparent.

I don't have any code in the site to make that change, that's why its strange and if i do the same thing with the Google Chrome browser then it doesn't happen. Internet explorer does something else strange: it reloads the site instead of changing the background color.

How can I find out why the Opera browser is doing this? Is there something like a browser console tracker where its show the reason the background color change happens?

I can't show you my site here with source code because it is a project for a client, but you can believe me I have written any Javascript code which could change the background color. Maybe you can help me find out why the browser is doing this.

Comment: Are you loading any dependencies? Or browser plugins?

Comment: maybe, my opera browser have a plugin which show a "search" or "copy" text when you click on somethink. but this background color change on this HTML element does not happen on all Div tags, its strange i also dont see infos in the console log from the browser

Comment: Try to disable all plugins. If the problem remains, try to remove your dependencies one by one and see when the issue disappears.

Answer (score 0):

add console log for click event and watch console.

Comment: i think this code helps:    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {

 // If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
 if (!event.target.matches('.click-me')) return;

 // Don't follow the link
 event.preventDefault();

 // Log the clicked element in the console
 console.log(event.target);

}, false);

Answer (score 0):

I think i found solution with following code:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
// If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
  if (!event.target.matches('.click-me')) return;
// Don't follow the link
  event.preventDefault();
// Log the clicked element in the console
  console.log(event.target);
}, false);
```

Comment: This answer only makes sense as a solution to other users if they can see the relevant “*[mcve]*” code in your question.